Strapi v5: How to associate a user with a Todo item during creation?
Here's my Todo model structure:
Todo
- title (Text)
- description (Text)
- completed (Boolean)
- users_permissions_user (Relation with User from users-permissions)



User
- username (Text)
- email (Email)
- provider (Text)
- password (Password)
- resetPasswordToken (Text)
- confirmationToken (Text)
- confirmed (Boolean)
- blocked (Boolean)
- role (Relation with Role from users-permissions)
- todos (Relation with Todo)

I've tried to create a Todo with the following request body:


{
  "data": {
    "title": "Your Todo Title",
    "description": "Your Todo Description",
    "completed": false,
    "users_permissions_user": {
      "connect": [3] // Replace with the actual user ID
    }
  }
}

But I'm getting this error:
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 400,
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Invalid key users_permissions_user",
        "details": {
            "key": "users_permissions_user",
            "path": "users_permissions_user",
            "source": "body"
        }
    }
}

I've also tried variations like:
{
  "data": {
    "title": "Your Todo Title",
    "description": "Your Todo Description",
    "completed": false,
    "users_permissions_user": 3
  }
}

And:
{
  "data": {
    "title": "Your Todo Title",
    "description": "Your Todo Description",
    "completed": false,
    "users_permissions_user": {
      "id": 3
    }
  }
}

But I'm still getting the same error.
How can I properly associate a user with a Todo item during creation in Strapi v5? Am I missing something in my model configuration or API request?

Check the permission for Users-permissions in API Tokens there should be allowed to find users.

For Strapi v5, the correct format for creating a Todo with a user association is:
{
  "data": {
    "title": "Your Todo Title",
    "description": "Your Todo Description",
    "completed": false,
    "user": 3
  }
}

The key difference is that in Strapi v5, you should use user instead of users_permissions_user in the request payload, even though the relation field might be named users_permissions_user in your model.
If you want to modify your Todo collection type to make this more explicit, you can update your schema configuration:
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "todos",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "todo",
    "pluralName": "todos",
    "displayName": "Todo"
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": false
  },
  "attributes": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "completed": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    },
    "user": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToOne",
      "target": "plugin::users-permissions.user",
      "inversedBy": "todos"
    }
  }
}

To create a Todo item with an associated user using the Strapi REST API, you can make a POST request:
curl -X POST http://localhost:1337/api/todos -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data": {"title": "Your Todo Title", "description": "Your Todo Description", "completed": false, "user": 3}}'

To automatically associate todos with the currently authenticated user in your custom controller, you can modify the create handler:
module.exports = createCoreController('api::todo.todo', ({ strapi }) => ({
  async create(ctx) {
    const user = ctx.state.user;
    const { data } = ctx.request.body;
    
    const newData = {
      ...data,
      user: user.id
    };
    
    const response = await super.create({ ...ctx, request: { body: { data: newData } } });
    return response;
  }
}));

Thank you.

Did you try enable User permission stuff? Go to Users & Permissions plugin > User-permissions >
and enable these chechboxes.
Note: Be sure these configuration is ok for your application structure and logic. Maybe you don't wanna give user details. Check, happy coding.
enter image description here
Strapi User Permissions
